# FactoryGirls multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, factory-bot

I'm having the hardest time thinking through this. I'm very new to FactoryGirl, so this may be explained clearly somewhere and I apologize if that is the case. This is certainly not a unique problem, maybe my Google skills aren't quite up to par.

I am working orders, which belong to category and belong to customer. I'm trying to build a customer who's placed 5 orders, however I keep throwing unique errors when it tries to build the category (which requires a unique name).

## features/customer_spec.rb

```
RSpec.feature "Customer management", :type => :feature do
    scenario "Customer with orders has order history" do
        customer = create(:customer, :with_5_completed_orders)
        visit customer_path(customer)
        expect(page).to have_content("Recent Orders")
    end
end
```

## factories/customers.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :customer do

        ...

        trait :with_5_completed_orders do
            after :create do |customer|
            create_list(:order_line, 5, :completed, :customer => customer)
        end
      end
   end
end
```

## factories/order_line.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :order_line do
        ....
        product
        ....
    end
end
```

## factories/product.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :product do |f|
        ....
        category
        ....
    end
end
```

## factories/categories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :category_name do |n|
      "category-#{n}"
    end

   factory :category do
       name { generate(:category_name) } 
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you have problem with category name uniqueness.

You can use [sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) to generate unique category names with FactoryGirl:

```
sequence :category_name do |n|
  "category-#{n}"
end

factory :category do
  name { generate(:category_name) } 
end
```

FactoryGirl's documentation on [sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) is worth reading too.

If your intention is to reuse the same category twice, you can first create one and reuse it in all orders:

```
trait :with_5_completed_orders do
  after :create do |customer|
    cat = generate(:category)
    create_list(:order_line, 5, :completed, customer: customer, category: cat)
  end
end
```

Comment: While that does address the uniqueness issue, what if I were to want to create five orders in the same category?

Comment: @RobertJohn where do you define order's category? I can't see it in your code

Comment: *correction* Order has a product, the product belongs to a category.

Comment: @RobertJohn I'm not sure about `order_line` structure. You can reuse category by creating it in `after :create` block

Comment: Do you mean I may have bad design, or I haven't provided enough information about the order_line structure?

Comment: @RobertJohn I mean information was not complete. Design as I can judge it is good.